# Tag or version a SQL Server CE database for future migrations?

Tags: .net, windows-installer, sql-server-ce

I have an application with a SQL Server CE private install. We want to give the user the option to keep the database on uninstall in case they re-install later or upgrade, which is my problem...

If they leave the database from version 1.5 of my app on the machine, then install version 2.0 how can I detect during installation of version 2.0 what version db they have?

Is there any way to tag or set metadata on an SQL Server CE database that can be read later?

The only alternative I have at the moment is to compare schemas which is not something I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a table with a single int column in the database with one row, containg the schema version.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I've used in the past was to create a "Version" table in the database.

In that table, you can include, at the very least, a single row, which contains the version of the application used to create the database.

You can then query the database (on first access, or during installation), check the value in that table, and update the database schema accordingly.

One advantage of such a method is that it make it easy to update from even "older" versions of your application - when your clients upgrade from version 1 to version 3 (without installing version 2). You create a "Database upgrader" method/class that upgrade from version X to version Y. You can then have multiple such upgraders... When you encounter a database that is not in the latest version, you keep upgrading it, each time with a more recent upgrader.